# Is it possible to read the a http post value using an inputstream?

Tags: java, xml, sax, xerces

I am http posting an xml file to a servlet, which is currently doing:

```
String xmlString = request.getParameter("xml");
```

I then convert the xml string variable into a StringReader and InputSource during a SAX parsing of the xml.

```
parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

I was curious if I could somehow get the value as an InputSource to begin with?

Performance counts for this, and converting things back and forth for no reason seems pointless if I can avoid it.

Comment: Any good reason that you are passing xml content as parameter and not part of the body?

Comment: @havexz what do you mean?  The xml is being posted via http post from a client.

Comment: thats what i m saying, why client is posting it as a parameter instead of passing as part of the http body (below the parameters). Like soap based post request.

Answer (score 4):

If your xml is a parameter, you can't do much. And, as JB Nizet and skaffman noted, you shouldn't worry about it. You have the thing only once in memory, and you perform reading only once.

But if the xml is the post body itself, then you can read it with:

```
parser.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")));
```

Comment: Beware of the file encoding, that is here assumed to be always UTF-8... which is not true. Moreover, using `request.getInputStream()` relies on the fact that the file is alone in the request payload which might not be the case as well.

Comment: 1. yes, but then it's obvious what to change (rather than relying on the platform encoding) 2. that's what I said ;)

Comment: 1. No Problem, I was sure you knew, it's just because it's a common mistakes, and don't want having @Blankman doin' it. 2. I didn't get your answer this way ^^. 3. What's still missing, and it is what added in my answer is the multipart way of updloading a file, which is for me at least the better way do manage files. 4. thanks answering

Answer (score 1):

You're not converting anything here. Just using a reader to read from the original String, and then an adapter to see the reader as an InputSource. Compared to IO, these operations cost absolutely nothing.

Comment: but isn't it then creating 2 copies of the same data in memory? a 100K xml file is now 200K in memory stored in both formats no?

Comment: No. The StringReader just has a *reference* to the String, and reads from it. The InputSource just stores a *reference* to the reader. If you mean that you have both the XML string, and the result of the parsing in memory, then yes, you're right. See Bozho's answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the recommended way to post file using HTTP is to use the `multipart/form-data` (check this [RFC-1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)).

Using this, you could even post multiple files, specifying their mime types AND their encoding -- most of answers are using UTF-8... but it is quite dangerous to assume that, `new StringReader(xmlString)` is almost equivalent but at bit more wrong since without givin' any encoding will leave the jvm fallback on the 'server' default encoding.

For handling such file upload w/o the overhead of a framework (such [Struts2](http://www.struts2.org/tutorials/struts2-upload-file-example.html)... in case you wish) is to use the [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) apache lib.

They recommend to use the classical API (rfc) but they provide another smart feature to use `stream` directly...

Now talking about the parsing, my POV is to use reader in **conjunction** with the mime-type (given by FileUpload) for the uploaded file. SO with FileUpload you'll have access to `FileItem` which has `item.getContentType()` helping you to create an `InputStreamReader` using this  [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)

## Edit

If you want to go w/ framework, even one step further that Struts 2. Here is what I'd recommend for reading which are very explicit tutorial on how deal w/ file upload using **Spring 3** [updload progly](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms-non-browsers) and [upload w/ Html](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)

Answer (score 0):

How do you send your XML? Is it possible to send the xml as HTTP-data and not as HTTP-parameter? Then you should be able to redirect the HttpInputStream to a InputSource without conveting it from a String.

But I think reading from a String will be quiet fast. Only if your xmldata is very large, you could have a performance issue because the data needs to be read completely to construct the String.